# How to configure Eclipse to build and link an additional custom library?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to write a basic weather monitoring station for the Pi in C++, I've got 2 sensors written as classes and I'm trying to do a basic program to implement these classes and test that they function as expected. When I try to build the project Eclipse replies with the following error messages which leads me to think I haven't included my header files correctly or something.

```
./src/HelloWorld.o: In function `main':
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:30: undefined reference to `pressureSensor::pressureSensor()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:31: undefined reference to `temperatureSensor::temperatureSensor()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:34: undefined reference to `pressureSensor::getReading()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:31: undefined reference to `temperatureSensor::~temperatureSensor()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:41: undefined reference to `pressureSensor::~pressureSensor()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:31: undefined reference to `temperatureSensor::~temperatureSensor()'
/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:41: undefined reference to `pressureSensor::~pressureSensor()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the `directory structure` for the project:

```
/workspaces
 - /src
   - /HelloWorld.cpp
 - /Sensors
   - /temperature.h
   - /temperature.cpp
   - /pressure.h
   - /pressure.cpp
```

And here are the files in question:

**/src/HelloWorld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include "../Sensors/pressure.h"
#include "../Sensors/temperature.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    if (wiringPiSetup()) {
        cout << "wiringPi is tangled, exiting." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "wiringPi is untangled and ready." << endl;
    }

    pinMode(0, INPUT);
    pinMode(1, INPUT);

    pullUpDnControl(0, PUD_UP);
    pullUpDnControl(1, PUD_UP);

    pressureSensor pressure;
    temperatureSensor temperature;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            cout << pressure.getReading() << endl;
        cout << "GPIO 17: " << digitalRead(0) << endl;
        cout << "GPIO 18: " << digitalRead(1) << endl;
        cout << endl;
        usleep(150000);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**/Sensors/pressure.h**

```
#ifndef PRESSURE_H_
#define PRESSURE_H_
#include "../BMP180/BMP180.h"

class pressureSensor {
public:
    pressureSensor();
    ~pressureSensor();
    int getReading();

private:
    SFE_BMP180 pressure;
      char status;
      double T,P,p0,a;
};

#endif /* PRESSURE_H_ */
```

**/Sensors/temperature.h**

```
#ifndef TEMPERATURE_H_
#define TEMPERATURE_H_

#define TMP102_ADDR 0x48
#define TMP102_CFGPTR1 0x01
#define TMP102_CFGREG1 0x61
#define TMP102_CFGREG2 0xA0
#define TMP102_CFGREGSO 0xE1

class temperatureSensor {
public:
    temperatureSensor();
    ~temperatureSensor();
    float getReading();

private:
    int TMPdevID;

};

#endif /* TEMPERATURE_H_ */
```

Comment: And your question is??  This may be a question about `c++` programming, in which case it would be better asked on `StackOverflow`. It does not appear to be specific to the Pi.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll re-ask it there.

Comment: first question, does `temerature.cpp` actially contain a definition for `temperatureSensor::temperatureSensor()` , and do you compile and link with it?

Comment: Are you building  with -c flag? When building project check if all files are compiled before linking.

Comment: Are you sure the source files for temperature.cpp and pressure.cpp are compiled and the resulting object files linked to your application?

Comment: Show us the makefile and/or the commands used to build the app

Comment: The error messages suggest that you haven't configured your build system correctly to build/link the sensors-related object files or libraries to your main application.